# Replace sequential numbers with a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

How can I find sequential numbers in a cell, and replace them with a range?
For example:

change:

> 1，3，5，15，16，17，25，28，29，31...

to:

> 1,3,5,15-17,25,28-29,31...

The numbers are already sorted, i.e. in increasing order.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow chen. Can you describe what things you have tried and where you are stuck?

Comment: @MattClarke  Do I need to change it into an array and loop through each number to see if the number after it is 1 more than it? How should I proceed from here?

Comment: Can you please edit your post add more to what your goal is? The logic in your example is hard to understand.

Comment: @VBAPete Sorry for the confusion. I want to change sequential numbers (eg. 15,16,17) to a range (15-17), and leave non-sequential numbers (eg. 1,3,5) as it is (1,3,5). Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An interesting question that I wanted to look at do without looping through a sequence (which would need sorting first) checking for sequential builds

This function

1. forces the string to a range address
2. uses `Union` to group consecutive rows together
3. manipulates the string to remove the column identifier

[image]

*loop wasn't necessary, shorter version!*

```
Function NumOut(strIn As String) As String
Dim rng1 As Range  
Set rng1 = Range("A" & Join(Split(Application.Trim([a1]), ", "), ",A"))
'force the range into areas rather than cells
Set rng1 = Union(rng1, rng1)
NumOut = Replace(Replace(Replace(rng1.Address, "$A$", vbNullstring), ": ", "-"), ",", ", ")
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: An extraordinary clever approach to use the tabular skeleton as base for an area-like grouping of numbers. +:)

Answer (score 4):

Thought I'd try an all-formulae solution using Microsoft365's `LET()` as a way to capture variables.

The below solution only counts 3+ consecutive numbers as ranges of numbers, not two.

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LET(X,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),Y,TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[preceding::*[1]+1=.][following::*[1]-1=.]")),SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,IF(MMULT(--(X=Y),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Y),,,0)),"-",X))&"</s></t>","//s[.*0=0 or (.='-' and preceding::*[1]*0=0)]")),",-,","-"))
```

Comment: Maybe worth some explanation to the `XPath` logic, impressive in any case +:) @JvdV

Answer (score 3):

While the given range/area based answer is interesting, it suffers from a couple of flaws:

- It is limited to an input string of 255 characters
- It is relatively slow

Here's a basic array loop based method.  It can handle long strings. In my testing it runs in about 1/3 the time.  It also has the bonus of not requiring the input to be sorted

```
Function NumOut2(strIn As String) As String
    Dim arrIn() As String
    Dim arrBuckets() As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim InRange As Boolean
    Dim mn As Long, mx As Long

    arrIn = Split(strIn, ", ")
    mn = arrIn(0)
    mx = arrIn(0)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrIn)
        If arrIn(i) < mn Then
            mn = arrIn(i)
        ElseIf arrIn(i) > mx Then
            mx = arrIn(i)
        End If
    Next

    ReDim arrBuckets(mn To mx)
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrIn)
        arrBuckets(arrIn(i)) = arrIn(i)
    Next
    NumOut2 = LBound(arrBuckets)
    InRange = False
    For i = LBound(arrBuckets) + 1 To UBound(arrBuckets)
        If arrBuckets(i) > 0 Then
            If arrBuckets(i) = arrBuckets(i - 1) + 1 Then
                If InRange Then

                Else
                    InRange = True
                    NumOut2 = NumOut2 & "-"
                End If
            Else
                If InRange Then
                    NumOut2 = NumOut2 & arrBuckets(i - 1) & ", " & arrBuckets(i)
                Else
                    NumOut2 = NumOut2 & ", " & arrBuckets(i)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            If InRange Then
                NumOut2 = NumOut2 & arrBuckets(i - 1)
            End If
            InRange = False
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.