# Combining consecutive numbers_Excel Formula or VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to find away to be able to combine consecutive numbers. It could be either by formula or VBA code, but I honestly don't know where to start and I could not find anything similar posted that I could use for my case.
Ex:

This:

```
9630184784, 9630184786, 9630184787, 9630184788, 9630184814, 9630184815, 9630184816, 9630184817
```

To:

```
9630184784, 9630184786-9630184788, 9630184814-9630184817
```

Thanks in advance!

Hyra

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace sequential numbers with a range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42150032/11683)

Comment: Interesting question and I agree with @GSerg that the linked duplicate should help you out. For your information, I have posted an all-formulae solution over there too. If this does not answer your question you'd have to rework your question to make it more clear and include your own attempt. Some pointers can be found over at [ask] a question with an [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
=MID(CONCAT(IFERROR(CHOOSE(MMULT(COUNTIF(A:A,A$1:A$8+{1,-1}),{1;3}/2)+1,",","-")&A1:A8,"")),2,99)
```

[image]

#Excel 2019

```
=MID(CONCAT(IFERROR(CHOOSE(MMULT(COUNTIF(A1,"*"&FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," </b><b>")&"</b></a>","a/b")+{1,-1}&"*"),{1;3}/2)+1,",","-")&FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," </b><b>")&"</b></a>","a/b"),"")),2,99)
```

#Excel 365

```
=LET(x,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," </b><b>")&"</b></a>","a/b"),MID(CONCAT(IFERROR(CHOOSE(MMULT(COUNTIF(A1,"*"&x+{1,-1}&"*"),{1;3}/2)+1,",","-")&x,"")),2,99))
```

Answer change from 象山海鲜.

Comment: Impressive +:); little drawback: the 2nd formula doesn't include 2 consecutive numbers at the string start (couldn't test the new `LET` function yet). - fyi You might be interested in a vba solution executing the **reverse action** at [Print sequence of consecutive and non-consecutive numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542020/print-using-sequence-of-consecutive-and-non-consecutive-numbers/61548385#61548385)

Answer (score 0):

This VBA function worked fine for me. It was posted by mikerickson at mrexcel.
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/convert-list-of-sequential-numbers-into-ranges.978486/

Function IntoRanges(aString As String, Optional Delimiter As String = ",") As String
Dim NextBit As String
Dim i As Long
Dim Items As Variant
Items = Split(aString, Delimiter)

```
IntoRanges = Items(0)
For i = 0 To UBound(Items) - 1
    If Val(Items(i)) + 1 = Val(Items(i + 1)) Then
        NextBit = "-" & Val(Items(i + 1))
    Else
        If NextBit = vbNullString Then
            IntoRanges = IntoRanges & Delimiter & Val(Items(i + 1))

        Else
            IntoRanges = IntoRanges & NextBit & Delimiter & Val(Items(i + 1))
            NextBit = vbNullString
        End If
    End If
Next i
IntoRanges = IntoRanges & NextBit
```

End Function